# Applescript Result (links as text) to URL

Tags: url, encoding, applescript

It seems not as easy as i thought it should be.

**My Script fetches Link URL's from websites**

**As of now, the resulting URL's are just text and i need them to be put out as URL's (clipboard or variable) to paste them into an email message**

I have tried various things from saving first to a rtf file and reading/pasting it to my email message body or copy and paste trough the clipboard.

Any help would be awesome as i can't get this solved since 2 days. Thanks

```
--prompt for keyword
display dialog "Keyword or Sentence" default answer "mad dog" buttons {"Done"} default button 1
set Keyword to text returned of the result

--create URL filter from Keyword
set my text item delimiters to " "
delay 0.2
set split_list to every text item of Keyword -- split in to list of everything between the spaces
set my text item delimiters to "-"
set Filter to (split_list as text) -- join, using the - as the delimter

--Open Pages
set site_url to "https://teespring.com/search?q=" & Keyword
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location site_url
end tell

-- wait until page loaded
property testingString : "Help" --Text on website to look for

set pageLoaded to false
tell application "Safari"
    repeat while pageLoaded is false
        set readyState to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1)
        set pageText to text of document 1

        if (readyState is "complete") and (pageText contains testingString) then set pageLoaded to true
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
end tell

-- get number of links
set theLinks to {}
tell application "Safari" to set num_links to (do JavaScript "document.links.length" in document 1)
set linkCounter to num_links - 1
-- retrieve the links
repeat with i from 0 to linkCounter
    tell application "Safari" to set end of theLinks to do JavaScript "document.links[" & i & "].href" in document 1
end repeat
theLinks
set nonExcludedURLs to {}

--Filter URLs
repeat with i from 1 to length of theLinks
    if item i of theLinks contains Filter then

        set end of nonExcludedURLs to item i of theLinks
    end if
end repeat
nonExcludedURLs


on page_loaded(timeout_value)
    delay 2
    repeat with i from 1 to the timeout_value
        tell application "Safari"
            if (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is "complete" then
                set nonExcludedURLs to {}

                return true
            else if i is the timeout_value then
                return false
            else
                delay 1
            end if

        end tell
    end repeat
    return false
end page_loaded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Maybe i described the problem not very well.

I just needed to split the resulting url's from a block of text to single lines with the following code:

```
set Single_URLs to "" 
repeat with this_line in nonExcludedURLs -- the URL's as block of text
    set Single_URLs to Single_URLs & this_line & return --split into lines
end repeat
```